# How to determine that a type received in the templated function is a list?

Tags: c++, list, templates

Let's suppose I have a templated function that just print the type it just received in its call.

```
template<typename T>
void printType()
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
    {
        printf("Type is int.\r\n");
    }
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
    {
        printf("Type is string.\r\n");
    }
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(MyList<int>))
    {
        printf("Type is a list.\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Type is not supported.\r\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    printType<int>();
    printType<std::string>();
    printType<MyList<int>>();
    return 0;
}
```

The support for the types the functions have to handle is limited to just some types: an int, a string and a list.

My problem is with the type MyList.
In my example code, the function handles just lists of ints, but I want to make it handle a list independent of the type of element it contains (ex.: `MyList<double>`, `MyList<std::string>`, `MyList<MyList<MyList<int>>>`, etc...).

This is just a representation of my problem in its very minimum possible.

How can I detected that the type provided by the function call is a MyList, regardless of the type element it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might specialize a struct (not a function) and omit typeid:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct MyList {};

namespace PrintType {

    template <typename T>
    struct Implementation {
        static void apply() {
            printf("Type is not supported.\r\n");
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct Implementation<int> {
        static void apply() {
            printf("Type is int.\r\n");
        }
    };

    // And more ...

    template <typename T>
    struct Implementation< MyList<T> > {
        static void apply() {
            printf("Type is a list.\r\n");
        }
    };
}

template <typename T>
void printType() {
    PrintType::Implementation<T>::apply();
}

int main()
{
    printType<int>();
    printType<std::string>();
    printType<MyList<int>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Type is int.
Type is not supported.
Type is a list.
```

Comment: As my real is little bit more complicated, it took me a while 'till get the hang of the template specialization. It works just fine. However, do I really need to do the specialization on the whole class (or struct)? Isn't possible to do all of that with just a given method of the class, for instance?

Comment: @Rickforce There is no way to specialize a template in a single class or function

Answer (score 3):

No need for `typeid` for this. Just use type T to dispatch to different overloads:

```
void printType_impl(int) {}

template<typename T>
void printType_impl(myList<T>) {}

void printType_impl(std::string) {}

template<typename T>
void printType()
{
    printType_impl(T());
}
```

If you're concerned about possible side effects of default-construction that the compiler is not allowed to optimize away, then have `printType_impl` take corresponding pointers instead and call it like `printType( static_cast<T*>(nullptr) );` instead.

Comment: With a `printType_impl` taking a pointer and called via `printType_impl((T*)0)` it is acceptable. There is no need to construct anything.

Comment: I'd count on the compiler to optimize it away.

Comment: @jork: What about side effects in the constructor !?

Comment: @Dieter fair enough. I believe this to be rare, but I ammended the answer.